# InfluxDB - create database via CURL command is failing

Tags: curl, influxdb

I'm trying to setup InfluxDB from Docker image. I was able to spin-up InfluxDB but not able to create database using following CURl command.

**CURl command**

```
curl -i -XPOST http://localhost:8086/query --header "Authorization: Token MY_INFLUX_TOKEN" --data-urlencode "q=CREATE DATABASE selenium"
```

**Error**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 18 Aug 2021 17:41:43 GMT
Content-Length: 76

{"results":[{"statement_id":0,"error":"not implemented: CREATE DATABASE"}]}
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: try to directly connect to terminal and check since above curl request is correct

Comment: @Arun Where you able to get the database created. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: you might be using legacy syntax, I ran into a similar error it turns I need to use /api/v2/...  https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.6/query-data/execute-queries/influx-api/